# What is UMS_Tooltip and why is it preventing classic asp pages from rendering

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-ui

I have a classic ASP page that's working fine on the web.

But locally I'm seeing only the header when I inspect element and in the body, which is weird, I see the following being rendered and NOT my page:

```
....</title></head><body><div id="UMS_TOOLTIP" style="position: absolute; cursor: pointer; z-index: 2147483647; background-color: transparent; top: -100000px; left: -100000px; background-position: initial initial; background-repeat: initial initial;"><img id="ums_img_tooltip" class="UMSRatingIcon"></div></body><umsdataelement id="UMSSendDataEventElement"></umsdataelement>...
```

Now, when I view source, however, my page code is all there.... there are no JS errors and nothing to indicate where this is coming from.

Has anyone ever heard of Universal Media Server (UMS) and what the heck this is and furthermore, why it's preventing my classic ASP page from rendering locally?

Other websites I'm building work fine, but this one....  On the web it renders... but I don't want to change anything....

Also, I'm getting an error in my IDE that says....

The document is looking for code for a widget that no longer exists: $( "#tabs" ).tabs();

But in reality, the widget DOES indeed exist and works fine.  This is ONLY in the editor.  I'm using JQuery 1.9.1 and JQuery UI 1.10.3

Thanks everyone.

Peter

UPDATE: I removed JQuery UI and the $("#tabs").tabs(); from the page and still the same but now I have this:

```
<umsdataelement id="UMSSendDataEventElement"></umsdataelement>
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Ah, D'OH!!!

This is the solution:

NEVER FORGET to PROPERLY close your Title Tag

```
<title>.../title> is what caused this stupid error.
```

Unbelievable

Answer (score -1):

As far as I can tell, this problem is caused by browser extension problems, not by failing to close a tag.  The solution I found was to turn off the Trend Micro antivirus extension, which caused this error for one of my clients.

Comment: The OP found their mistake 5 years ago, and now you are telling them that isn't the problem? You're blaming it on Anti Virus which the OP never mentioned?

Comment: This is the first google result for a UMS_TOOLTIP error, and as far as I can tell it is always caused by the Trend Micro browser extension.  I'm trying to help people who get here from googling the error.  Sorry if I sounded "snooty", I didn't mean to.  I edited it to sound less so.

Comment: @ChrisMM Well David B is absolutely right, this is caused by Trend Micro toolbar extention. I too just faced this issue, and when I tested it by disabling the Trend Micro toolbar, the error was gone.