# Regex to return only string between braces in the last level

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, regex

I have a JSON returning:

```
    {
      "status": 1,
      "message": "1",
      "data": {
        "file": "1.png"
      },
      "html": "",
      "redirect_to": ""
    }
<divid="UMS_TOOLTIP"style="position: absolute; cursor: pointer; z-index: 2147483647; background: transparent; top: -100000px; left: -100000px;"></div>
```

I would like to clean up, returning only the content

```
{"status":1,"message":"1","data":{"file":"1.png"},"html":"","redirect_to":""}
```

I tried `\{\{([^}]*)\}\}`, but it doesn't seem to work in my tests.
What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: It might be better to fix whatever source is providing you with that broken data

Comment: use regex /{.*}/ here is a link: https://regexr.com/44gi8

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try to create a group in following way:

- Starts with `{`
- Can have anything `.*`
- Ends with `}`
- And does not follow any closing braces using `(?!})`

**Note:** This will not work properly if you have many stringified objects along with markup. Eg. `{...}<div>...</div>{...}` For such cases, this will fail.

```js
var regex = /({.*}(?!}))/;
var str = '{"status":1,"message":"1","data":{"file":"1.png"},"html":"","redirect_to":""}<div id="UMS_TOOLTIP" style="position: absolute; cursor: pointer; z-index: 2147483647; background: transparent; top: -100000px; left: -100000px;"></div>';

console.log(str.match(regex)[0])
```

Answer (score 2):

One option would be to use `XRegExp` to recursively match nested `{` and `}`s until they're balanced:

```js
const input = `{"status":1,"message":"1","data":{"file":"1.png"},"html":"","redirect_to":""}<div id="UMS_TOOLTIP" style="position: absolute; cursor: pointer; z-index: 2147483647; background: transparent; top: -100000px; left: -100000px;"></div>`;
const json = '{' + XRegExp.matchRecursive(input, '{', '}') + '}';
// second parameter is the left recursive delimiter
// third parameter is the right recursive delimiter
console.log(JSON.parse(json));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/xregexp/3.2.0/xregexp-all.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Since its a library ref, it would be really nice if you can extend the scope of your answer to cover few other obvious cases.

Answer (score 1):

The unwanted appended `<div id="UMS_TOOLTIP" ...>` causing the issue (as it's not JSON) could *possibly* be unrelated to your code.

A client of ours experienced this and confirmed they were running Trend Micro antivirus security, which aligns with similar reports for the same issue:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/59412958/6833854
- http://forums.delphiforums.com/service/messages/52267/1

Answer (score 0):

Assuming, your JSON returns the following:

```
{
    "status":1,
    "message":"1",
    "data":{"file":"1.png"},
    "html":"",
    "redirect_to":""
}
<div id="UMS_TOOLTIP" style="position: absolute; cursor: pointer; z-index: 2147483647; 
background: transparent; top: -100000px; left: -100000px;"></div>
```

Everyone has given very insightful answers. But if this is not a very major step in your program you might want to implement this:

```
var result = `{"status":1,"message":"1","data":{"file":"1.png"},"html":"","redirect_to":""}<div id="UMS_TOOLTIP" style="position: absolute; cursor: pointer; z-index: 2147483647; background: transparent; top: -100000px; left: -100000px;"></div>`;
var retur = result.match('<');
console.log(result.slice(0, retur.index));
```

For your log to be this:

```
{
    "status":1,
    "message":"1",
    "data":{"file":"1.png"},
    "html":"",
    "redirect_to":""
}
```

PS: This is not a recommended patch to do, but is just a trivial way to get the job done.